# Multiple calls of a function inside other functions

Tags: python

I have the following functions:

```
def f(x):
    return x

def f2(x):
    y = f(x)
    return y + x + 1

def f3(x):
    y = f(x)
    return y + x + 2

def DoAll(x):
    i2 = f2(x)
    i3 = f3(x)
    return i2, i3

print(DolAll(2))
```

Even when this code runs, it seems very inefficient since I call `f(x)` multiple times. How can I solve this problem without defining an `f2(x, y)` and `f3(x, y)`? I would like to use something similar to

```
def f(x):
    return x

def f2(x):
    nonlocal y
    return y + x + 1

def f3(x):
    nonlocal y
    return y + x + 2

def DoAll(x):
    y = f(x)
    f2 = f2(x)
    f3 = f3(x)
    return f2, f3

print(DolAll(2))
```

Of course, the code shown here does not work.

Comment: Note that it doesn't work because Python uses lexical scopes, not dynamic scopes. `y` comes a scope `f2` et al. are *defined* in, not *called* in.

Comment: *it seems very inefficient since I call f(x) multiple times* but is your code objectively taking too much time to complete? If not you might be attempting to do so-called premature optimization, which is generally undesired

Comment: @chepner. It works fine if you use caching...

Comment: @Daweo. Let's assume that we can trust OP's conclusion, if not their reasoning.

Comment: @MadPhysicist You mean instead of `nonlocal`? Sure, because you actually define all the local variables. You are still repeating the call to `f`; you just (potentially) reduce the amount of time each call takes.

Comment: @chepner. I would argue that two or three dict lookups is a good trade for a long computation. Especially since you only have to traverse the nested structure once.

Comment: I'm not disputing that; I'm just talking about the OP's attempt to use nonlocal variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use caching to avoid redoing the computation. Python provides such functionality out-of-the-box with [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache):

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def f(x):
    ...
```

This is more general than just making the value globally available, since it will allow multiple computations to stash values simultaneously.

If your functions are deterministic and without side-effects, you can short-circuit out the computation of nested calls entirely by caching all the intermediate results too:

```
@lru_cache()
def f(x):
    print(f'Called f({x})')
    return x

@lru_cache()
def f2(x):
    print(f'Called f2({x})')
    y = f(x)
    return y + x + 1

@lru_cache()
def f3(x):
    print(f'Called f3({x})')
    y = f(x)
    return y + x + 2

@lru_cache()
def DoAll(x):
    print(f'Called DoAll({x})')
    i2 = f2(x)
    i3 = f3(x)
    return i2, i3

>>> DoAll(1)
Called DoAll(1)
Called f2(1)
Called f(1)
Called f3(1)
(3, 4)

>>> DoAll(2)
Called DoAll(2)
Called f2(2)
Called f(2)
Called f3(2)
(5, 6)

>>> DoAll(1)
(3, 4)
```

Notice that the expensive computation only gets performed once for each new input.

Answer (score 3):

You missed one `nonlocal` declaration: in `DoAll` itself. (You could use `global` as well, since the only non-local scope in this example is the global scope.) This would cause the `y` variable to be defined in a scope visible to `f2` and `f3`.

```
def DoAll(x):
    nonlocal y
    y = f(x)
    f2 = f2(x)
    f3 = f3(x)
    return f2, f3
```

However, this should start to resemble a crude attempt at defining a class that encapsulates `y` for all its methods to share.

```
class Foo:

    def f(self, x):
        return x

    def f2(self, x):
        return self.y + x + 1

    def f3(self, x):
        return self.y + x + 2

    def DoAll(self, x):
        self.y = self.f(x)
        f2 = self.f2(x)
        f3 = self.f3(x)
        return f2, f3

foo = Foo()
print(foo.DoAll(2))
```

(This in itself is a fairly awkward class design, as the `y` attribute gets defined on an ad-hoc basis, but it should hint at the use of the object itself providing the "scope" from which other methods can access a shared, non-local value `y`.)

In the end, `Foo` itself is basically providing a context in which the return value of `Foo.f` is cached for use by `Foo.f2` and `Foo.f3`. There are much cleaner ways to implement such a cache, so I'll direct you to [Mad Physicist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71767708/1126841).

Comment: This is a neat solution, but very awkward as you say. It's basically a one-element cache without the key :)

Comment: Yeah, I should point that out explicitly ;)